# Editor to design the forms and widgets in flutter

Tags: forms, layout, widget, flutter

Currently, all layouts, forms and widgets in the flutter application are created "manually" by writing code. It isn't comfortable. Is it planned to create a special editor to design the forms and save them as an application resource (as in the java android SDK) or even a third-party file, or save it as a resource with subsequent automatic code generation (as in .NET)?

Comment: This is the concept of Flutter. I do not even think that a GUI would make sense at all because build trees do not just consist of simple widgets.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no such feature.

You can follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2347

As mentioned in the comments it's probably not too helpful anyway because how would you represent different layouts depending on conditional code inside the widgets `build` method.

Android Studio/IntelliJ has lots of features in "Flutter Inspector" to help you debug the UI and investigate its structure and there is more in the works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, there's no visual editor and it would be tricky to do well given the conditional code/layouts/etc. However, there is a web-based editor you can use for static layouts: https://flutterstudio.app/